# How do I randomly start activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, random

I'm looking to randomly start activities in android studio without repetition. I'd like to be able to start an activity randomly by clicking a button and in an 'if' statement. Whoever can help out that would be fantastic! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

```
   ArrayList<Class> activities = new ArrayList<>();


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       //your codes...
       activities.add(History.class);
       activities.add(Bookmark.class);
       activities.add(Themes.class);  

       //your codes

   }



public void openActivity(Class class_) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, class_);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void openRandomActivity(){

    Class that = activities.get(new Random().nextInt(activities.size()));

    activities.remove(that); // after using, remove from list

    openActivity(that);
}
```

Call `openRandomActivity` when a user click to button.

Comment: So, you **always** want to launch different `activity` when user click to button in that **session**? `openRandomActivity()` method getting random Activity from list.

Comment: Thats what is said in the question i think

Comment: So I edited my answer. He should be more clear about what he say.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'll check to see if this works. I'm also assuming you call openRandomActivity(); in an if statement as well?